# Is it possible to replace "to notify" with "notifying" in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

> According to Gwangjin Police Station, the 19-year-old Kim, an employee
>   of a company that Seoul Metro had subcontracted for door maintenance,
>   had been repairing the platform screen door at Guui Station on
>   Saturday evening.
>
> **He was working by himself, with neither supervisor nor any signboard to notify approaching train operators.**
>
> The authorities have examined surveillance camera recordings and are
>   set to summon related officials for questioning. The probe will be
>   jointly handled by the Ministry of Employment and Labor’s special
>   judicial police and the Korea Occupational Safety and Health Agency.

Is it possible to replace "to notify" with "notifying" in the sentence? 
and if it possible to do that, is meaning changed after that?

Comment: Could add sentences before and after that sentence above? Right now it can have 2 meanings (that im aware of)

Comment: yes i did, but i wonder also your 2 meanings

Comment: This seems to have already been answered very well. With only the bolded sentence i assumed:
It was either:  
 his job to notify the trains, however he couldn't do that because of the lack of a supervisor or the signboard 
**or** he was working on something (like on the tracks) but because there was no supervisor or signboard the train operators would not be notified

Comment: Do this sentence have ambiguity? can we confuse who or what to notify approaching train operators? so when his job to notify, there are no supervisor or signboard but i think he still would do his job. doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can replace it, but indeed the meaning will slightly change.

> He was working by himself, with neither supervisor nor any signboard to notify approaching train operators.

This means that the reason or function of the supervisor or signboard would have been to notify approaching train operators of the fact that someone was working there. Even if no trains would have approached, signboard could have been there *in order to notify* them.

> He was working by himself, with neither supervisor nor any signboard notifying approaching train operators.

Now the sentence describes the *action* of the supervisor or signboards. Even if the signboard would have been placed there for another reason, they were effectively notifying approaching operators (if the signs would haven been present).

Normally, we put warning signs somewhere with a certain goal. *To notify* would therefore be the common way to phrase the given sentence. If whatever the warning signs did was different from what we would put them up for, this could be indicated by describing their action:

> Although warning signs had been put up *to notify* approaching train operators, they actually contributed to the dangerous situation by *confusing* the operators.

Comment: @JavaLatte thanks, I removed it :) (You would have been welcome to do so yourself as well, of course :) )